# Save image in a folder and directly use XCode

Tags: xcode, photoshop

I was wondering whether it is possible to save an image you just edited in Photoshop, and immediately it is useable in XCode, instead of dragging the image into XCode all the time.

Comment: It's called Xcode. (Not XCode, xCode, Eclipse or any other name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a folder reference to the location you are saving your images.

To do this, use the "*Add Files to 'NameOfProject'*" menu command, then select your folder. Ensure that the options are set as follows:

[image]

Then the images should appear in Xcode when you view the contents of that folder. When referencing them, you must use the name of the folder. E.g. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImages/image.png"];`

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to do that in the past. But couldn't figure it out. Now I think about it, it's pretty straight forward.